# No tests found in junit4

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am trying to use the Junit4 i using the below clases

```
public class Example extends TestCase {

    public Example(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    @Test
    public void exampletest() {
        //TO DO
    }
}

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Example.class })
public class Tests {
    TestSuite tests = new TestSuite();
        tests.addTest(new Example("exampletest"));  
}
```

It gives me No tests found in junit4 exception some one can tell me why i get this exception
Or give an example how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

In JUnit4, you don't make your test cases extend *TestCase*. But if you do, then your *@Test* annotations are ignored, and you have to prepend test method names by *test*.
Try this code:

Example.java:

```
import org.junit.Test;
public class Example {
    @Test
    public void exampletest() {
        //TO DO
    }
}
```

Tests.java:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Example.class })
public class Tests {
}
```

Comment: I mean i need to order the test cases so i am using  TestSuite tests = new TestSuite();
        tests.addTest(new Example("exampletest"));  can you give some advice.

Comment: By design, JUnit doesn't allow to speculate on the order in which the tests are executed. TestCases are supposed to be independent. Fair enough when you are writting new tests. Another story when you have to work with legacy tests. Have a look at this: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/manipulation/Sorter.html

Comment: You might need to write your own Runner to achieve what you want. You could derivate the *Suite* runner, and use Request.sortWith to order the test case execution.

Comment: you have two questions up. Handle them seperated.